# OnStop in services methods for ending the worker thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, service

I'm currently looking into services under c# and looked how OnStart should be programmed (with worker threads so that OnStart is not blocking),... .
Now what I'm wondering about is how the worker threads (if they are endless loops) should be stopped when OnStop is called. As I know Thread.Abort is quite a bad praxis my first thought was to use a cancellation token like in this example:

```
Class MyServiceClass : ServiceBase
{
    ......
    bool serviceFinished;
    Thread worker;

    protected void OnStart(string[] args)
    { 
       serviceFinished = false;
       worker = new Thread (MyFunction);
       worker.Name = "MyFunctionWorker";
       worker.IsBackground = false;  //This is important to set!
       worker.Start();
    }

    private void MyFunction()
    {
        while (serviceFinished == false)
        {
             ..... // Do whatever I want to do in this function
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        serviceFinished = true;
        worker.Join(new TimeSpan(0,2,0));
    }
```

So I'm using sort of a cancellation token there. Now like I mentioned my question is: Is 
this how threads in services are to be handled and to be ended or should the ending of threads in a service be done in a completely different way?

Comment: Use the `CancellationToken` class for your cancellation token.  Don't just use a boolean variable.

Comment: Yes, that's about it. @Servy: is there a reason why a volatile bool field wouldn't do in this case?

Comment: @Servy any special circumstances there that make the class better suited than a (volatile) boolean?

Comment: @Groo You should avoid using very low level features precisely because it's not necessarily a trivial question to answer.  It might be fine, but it's far easier and safer to use a tool specifically designed for the job so that you can *know* that it's fine.

Comment: @ThomasE. Yes.  It's specifically designed to do this exact task.  It conveys the exact semantic meaning of your requirements, ensures correct synchronization of data between threads, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is OK, but please use

```
volatile bool serviceFinished
```

because otherwise compiler optimizations may replaced your

```
while (serviceFinished == false)
```

as

```
while (false)
```

For more info read msdn volatile http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx

Comment: Compiler might cache the value, but it certainly won't remove the expression completely.

Comment: @user2126375 good point with volatile! I had completely overlooked that thing.

Comment: Groo - see this http://vanillajava.blogspot.cz/2012/01/demonstrating-when-volatile-is-required.html I was writing about similar issue.